# flex/ actionscript comments

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, asdoc

cannot get the comments to show in actionscript file when running asdoc.. is this a known bug?

```
[Bindable]
/** test comment */
public var currentSearchTextValue:String;
```

does not show anything in the generated documentation... am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[Bindable]` actually generates code that wraps the property, so it might not be possible. Try moving `[Bindable]` to after your comments, but failing that you might be out of luck I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't see anything wrong here, I would follow the ASDOC best practices - putting the comments in separate line with a preceding asterisk as suggested [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=asdoc_3.html) and see if that works.

```
[Bindable]
/**
* Test comment
*/
public var currentSearchTextValue:String;
```

Comment: doesn't work either, I believe it is related to the "[Bindable]" tag. When I remove it, it works properly

Comment: Did you try to set [Bindable] after comments?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue and have posted a detailed question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356713/using-asdoc-with-bindable-metatag-and-mxml). no answers yet.

One workaround is to use an event name along with the Bindable tag

```
[Bindable("someEvent")]
/*
* asdoc comment
* */
public var currentSearchTextValue:String;
```

but this wud require u to dispatch "someEvent" manually to get binding work. So u might wanna use this for generating asdoc alone and change it back to the older version afterwards.